# Wordpress not meeting speed standards

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed

I am having trouble improving my wordpress site for [capsule sizes](https://www.capsulesizes.com)
we have w3 total cache activated, is there any more what we can do without interfering with wooCommerce?

Comment: hi! you can try this *How to Speed up WordPress Leveraging Browser Caching via .htaccess* https://crunchify.com/how-to-speed-up-wordpress-leveraging-browser-caching-via-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the community! These steps worked out very well for me, so I think they might help you too.

1. Update your php version to the latest version. (in cPanel go to PHP configuration)
2. Enable GZIP compression. [See Tutorial](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/enable-gzip-compression/)
3. Try Cache Enabler plug-in instead of w3 total cache, it's lighter and it gave me better results. [Learn more](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cache-enabler/)
4. Try Autoptimize plug-in. [Learn more](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/)
5. Try Async JavaScript plug-in. [Learn more](https://wordpress.org/plugins/async-javascript/)
6. Optimize your Database. [See tutorial](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9791/2180/how-to-optimize-website-database)
7. Try LazyLoad plug-in for images. [Learn more](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rocket-lazy-load/)

Remember that even if you try different plug-ins and settings (like the above) to speed-up your site, it is crucial to follow basic optimisation habits to get better results. Here are just a few:

1. Find a good WordPress web hosting.
2. Use light-weight WordPress themes. I recommend StoreFront or Astra with WooCommerce
3. Keep your plug-ins updated.
4. Always compress your images and avoid unnecessary oversizes.
5. Insert in-line scripts in the footer to avoid render blocking. [See tutorial](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/add-code-wordpress-header-footer/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go, I kept getting around 80 on google page speed, was hoping to get it up to 90, hopefully what you recommend helps

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.capsulesizes.com%2F&tab=desktop

Comment: From your recommendations I managed to get it up to 93 for desktop and 63 for mobile, will settle for that.

Comment: Not bad Danny, I'm glad it worked. Please mark my answer as accepted if it help you. Thank you!